# Vlasov Poisson: linear momentum conservation

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, hyperbolic-pde

The 3-dimensional Vlassov -Poisson equation I am studying at university is
$$ \partial_t f (t,x,v) + v\cdot \nabla_x f (t,x,v) - \nabla_x \phi (t,x) \nabla_v f (t,x,v) =0,$$
where $$\Delta \phi = 4\pi\gamma \rho (t,x,v) \text{ and } \rho (t,x) = \int_{\mathbb{R}^3} f(t,x,v)\ dv$$

I am trying to prove the momentum is conserved:
$$q(t) = \int_{\mathbb{R}^6} vf(t,x,v)\ dxdv \Rightarrow  q' (t)=0$$

**I need some help to prove that** This is my attempt,
I first substitute the equation of $f$ into the expression:
$$ q'(t) = \int \partial_t [vf(t,x,v)]\ dxdv = \int v [-v\cdot \nabla_x f (t,x,v) + \nabla_x \phi (t,x) \nabla_v f (t,x,v)]\ dxdv$$
Secondly, I noticed that the first term is equal to zero after an integration by parts (passing the $x$-derivative to $|v|^2$ which does not depende on $x$), therefore
$$ q'(t)= \int v\nabla_x\phi(t,x)\nabla_v f(t,x,v)\ dxdv $$
**What can I do next to show that $q' =0$?** Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It helps to consider components of $q$, in order to keep the notations clear. From what you have we can write

$$  q_i'(t) = \int v_i \sum_{j} \nabla_{x_j} \phi \nabla_{v_j} f ~\mathrm{d}x ~\mathrm{d}v $$

integrate by parts in $v$, and using that $\phi$ is independent of $v$ and $\nabla_{v_j} v_i = \delta_{ij}$ we get

$$ q_i'(t) = - \int \nabla_{x_i} \phi  f ~\mathrm{d}x ~\mathrm{d}v $$

perform the $v$ integral first since $\phi$ is $v$-independent

$$ q_i'(t) = - \int \nabla_{x_i} \phi \rho ~\mathrm{d}x $$

by definition, and using the definition of the gravitational potential you get

$$ q_i'(t) = - \frac{1}{4\pi\gamma} \int \nabla_{x_i} \phi \Delta \phi ~\mathrm{d}x $$

Integrating by parts the Laplacian you get

$$ q_i'(t) =  \frac{1}{8\pi\gamma} \int \nabla_{x_i} ( |\nabla\phi|^2 ) ~\mathrm{d}x = 0 $$

Comment: Nice! Thank you very much Willie +1